# How to include a time zone in the way formatted slack dates are displayed?

Tags: slack-api

The ability to use [date formatting in the Slack API](https://api.slack.com/messaging/composing/formatting#date-formatting) to display a date/time in the local timezone of the person seeing the message is great, but I'd like people to *know* that the date/time is in their local timezone.

Using `<!date^1392734382^{date_short_pretty} {time}|2014-02-18 6:39 AM PST>` will display as "Posted Feb 18, 2014 6:39 AM" if the receiver is in California, and "Posted Feb 18, 2014 8:39 AM" if the receiver is in Chicago (see [here](https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder?mode=message&blocks=%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22section%22%2C%22text%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22mrkdwn%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%3C!date%5E1392734382%5E%7Bdate_short_pretty%7D%20%7Btime%7D%7C2014-02-18%206%3A39%20AM%20PST%3E%22%7D%7D%5D) in Block Kit Builder) but there is no indication to the receivers that the date/time is in their own timezone.

Is there any way to include the receiver's time zone as part of the token string?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature that is provided by the API. The only solution I can think of is to add some info text like "(local time)" to the datetime output in your message.